# Selecting cases based on values in previous cases

Tags: spss

I've got the following list in SPSS:

```
Subjekt    Reactiontime       correct/incorrect
1          x                  1
1          x                  0
1          x                  1
1          x                  0
```

I now want to select all rows/cases that follow AFTER "0" (in the column correct/incorrect) because I want to compute the mean of all reactiontimes that come after "0".

How can I do that in SPSS?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to add a column that keeps track of whether the prior row was equal to 0 in your `correct` field and then calculate the mean `Reactiontime` of those cases.

First let's make a variable to flag cases we want included in the average.

```
* set prev_correct to 0 if the prior case was 0 .
IF (LAG(correct)=0) prev_correct=0 .
* else set to -1 .
RECODE prev_correct (SYSMIS=-1) .
EXE .
```

Now we can calculate the mean reaction time, splitting by our new variable.

```
MEANS Reactiontime BY prev_correct /CELLS MEAN .
```

Or, if we only want to output the mean when prev_correct=0 .

```
TEMP .
SELECT IF prev_correct=0 .
MEANS Reactiontime /CELLS MEAN .
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter approach (though less generic than @user45392's full process):

```
if lag(correct)=0 ReactiontimeAfter0=Reactiontime.
```

now you can just run `means ReactiontimeAfter0`.